# Extracting indivdual digits from a number.

Tags: java, arrays, numbers

I am trying to extracting a individual number from a given integer. example from 1234, I want to store  1 , 2 ,3 ,4 in an array.The number of digits might not be same every time. I don't know how to initialize the array for the same.

```
int number = 1234;

int [] a = new int[];

for(int i =0;i<lengthOfNum;i++){
    a[i] = digitReturn();
}
```

Comment: Do you want the individual digits as `int` values? Or does it not matter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try the following:

```
int number = 1234;
int length = Integer.toString(number).length();
int[] a = new int[length];

int index = length - 1;
for (int i = 0; i < length; i++){
    a[i] = number % 10;
    number = number / 10;
    index--;
}
```

Convert the number to String to get the size and use that value to declare the length of the array and then just loop through it, extracting the last number using modulus and then dividing to get rid of the last digit in the integer.

Comment: No problem, I just realized that the order is actually going to be reversed (i.e. you'll get 4321 instead of 1234 if you go about it this way) If you want the correct order, refer to my latest changes - you'd just be filling the array backwards.

Answer (score 0):

Convert the number into a string, then split the string into an array. After that, convert the characters into integers, like this:

```
int number = 1234;
List<Integer> digits = ArrayList<Integer>();
String digitsAsString = ("" + number).split("");
for(String digitAsString:digitsAsString){
    digits.add(new Integer(Integer.parseInt(digitAsString));
}
```

Your array of digits is the list of `digits`

Comment: I don't want to use list, I want to use array.

Comment: You can use digits.toArray()

Comment: Or you can build your method around String.charAt() like bakalolo, below, which fits nicely with an array. Using .split() seems very slightly excessive.

Answer (score 0):

```
int number = 4567;
String number_string = String.valueOf(number);
char[] chars = number_string.toCharArray();
int[] digits = new int[chars.length];
int i = 0;
for (char c : chars) {
    digits[i] = c - '0';
    i++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int number = 1234;
String num = Integer.toString(number);
int [] a = new int[num.length()];

for(int i = 0; i < num.length(); i++){
    a[i] = Character.getNumericValue(num.charAt(i));
}
```

First convert number to a String, loop through each char and convert them into an int then storing the value into a.